# JavaFX Stage and Shape size mismatch

Tags: javafx

I'm having a problem where the size that I set a `Stage` to be is not actually the size that it appears to be. The problem can be seen with the following code:

```java
public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        Rectangle shape = new Rectangle(450, 100);
        shape.setFill(Color.GRAY);
        pane.getChildren().add(shape);
        stage.minWidthProperty().set(450);
        stage.setTitle("Test");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Initially, when the stage becomes visible, it appears to be the same width as the rectangle, both are 450 pixels wide. `shape.getWidth()` does return `450.0`, but strangely, `stage.getWidth()` returns `466.0`.

I can also resize the window by clicking and dragging, and when I make it the minimum width I can, `stage.getWidth()` returns `450.0`, as expected, but it is cutting off part of the rectangle, and by screenshotting it and cucking it into paint, I found that the stage in actually only 434 pixels wide.

Why is this happening, and, more importantly, is there anything I can do about it?

Some extra notes in case it's relevant: I'm running JavaFX 11.0.2, OpenJDK 16.0.1, and windows 10 build 19043

Comment: Stage size includes window decorations (borders and title bars), scene size does not. The area needed to render window decorations can change depending upon the OS, window/stage type, windowing system, and windowing system settings.  In terms of what, if anything, to do about it, that depends, what do you want to accomplish?  You don't say that in your question.

Comment: @jewelsea That makes sense, but there's no border or title bars on the side (at least that I can see). Is space reserved for them automatically maybe? As to what I am trying to accomplish, I want to make sure that bits of the UI aren't cut off when the user resizes the window. I'll probably just add a constant (`stage.minWidthProperty().set(450 + 16)`) or something like that, I was just concerned because I wasn't sure what was causing the width to be different from what I expected.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to make sure that bits of the UI aren't cut off when the user resizes the window. I'll probably just add a constant `(stage.minWidthProperty().set(450 + 16))`.

The original question is a classic [X/Y question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  You don't really want the stage and scene to be the same size.

Forget about trying to limit the stage size to a specific number or to the expected size of your scene.  It is incorrect to do so because the number will change based upon window decoration size.  Window decoration size will vary across OS, window types, and implementations.  So, while you might get it to look good on your test system using a hardcoded padding number for the presumed decoration size, it might look wrong or weird as soon as a user tries running the app under different conditions (like using a different OS).

Instead let the JavaFX system work out what the preferred size for the stage is, then set the minimum size of the stage to the preferred size.

```
stage.setScene(myScene);
stage.show();
stage.setMinHeight(stage.getHeight());
stage.setMinWidth(stage.getWidth());
```

When you show the scene, JavaFX will automatically size the scene to its preferred size and allocate the appropriately sized window (including decorations such as title bars and borders) to fit that scene.  Once it has done that, if you set the minimum height and width for the stage to the current height and width of the stage, the stage cannot be resized to include a display that is smaller than the original preferred size of the scene.

One of the nice things about a windowing system is that it can be used to resize windows to arbitrary sizes.  Consider carefully if you want to place this restriction on your users to not be able to do this with your application.